# How do I trigger a webhook for transaction settlement in sandbox?

Tags: braintree

I am trying to create a new webhook endpoint for my braintree integration. I added an endpoint to the Control Panel. I am using the Python library and created a a bunch of transactions. Also, I manually settled the transaction using the testing gateway. But I do not get a webhook notification. When is the webhook triggered and I=is there a way to trigger it manually?

Comment: What kind of webhook triggers did you set up? There isn't any webhook trigger for a settled transaction if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: I am using the "Transaction -> Disbursed" webhook. I got the webhook notification later in the day. I can always create the test notification from the SDK but that doesn't seem to have all the data in the actual notification.

Comment: Sorry noob question. Does Transaction -> Disbursed webhook cover voided transactions?

Comment: @jerry a settled transaction - or even a pending one would be a great candidate for a webhook. What happens if my internet connection times out when charging a customer? We get an email a month later from an angry customer because we charged them and didn't ship anything! A webhook would be a perfect way to reconcile everything and make sure all our locally maintained transactions are in sync.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The `Transaction -> Disbursed` webhook fires when the transaction has settled, and braintree has begun to move funds from their account to yours. While settling the transaction manually in the control panel would start the process, it does not fire the webhook right away.

There isn't any way to trigger this manually, instead braintree has [sample payloads](https://developer.paypal.com/braintree/docs/guides/webhooks/testing-go-live/ruby#sample-payload-and-signature) and a way to trigger a ["Check" webhook](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/reference/general/testing/ruby#trigger-a-test-notification-from-braintree) in the control panel.

To answer the question in your comment, this type of webhook does not cover voided transactions.

Comment: This is the second reference I've seen to sample payloads that points to a seemingly dead link. Do you know if they still exist and if so where I can find them now?

Answer (score 5):

I also asked a similar question to Braintree support, and the answer may be useful for others, even if I decided to go with Stripe (I found stripe much better after all my tests ;).

**Question**

Hi,

Just integrating Braintree, but can’t find how I’m supposed to get a transaction confirmation (meaning it has correctly been ‘charged’). When I create a ‘transaction.sale’ (including submitForSettlement) I always get (sandbox) a response indicating the status ‘Submitted for settlement’, and the transaction doesn't go to settled until Braintree globally process it (at night, etc.). I also can’t find a related webhook to get payment confirmation (as I currently get using PayPal - IPN).

When/how can I get a payment confirmation so I can then ‘deliver’ the purchased item? By checking your docs, it’s like you can’t get a confirmation until the next day… how does it work exactly?

Thank you!

---

**Answer**

Hi Nacho,

Thanks for reaching out!

A Braintree transaction goes through several steps, the second of which is submitted for settlement. This means that the money has begun to move from the customers account, and is the immediate state of a transaction after being submitted; it's not possible to get an immediate 'settled' or 'complete' status on submission. Transactions in this state will generally move to settling, then settled, within 24 hours, although it can depend on your processing bank.

It is very unusual for a transaction to fail when moving from submitted for settlement to settled, as the amount will have been authorised prior to submission for settlement. Authorising a transaction means the funds are put on hold within the customers account, for a certain timeframe depending on payment method, until they are settled. We get an immediate response from the processing bank as to whether an authorisation is successful, which you'll see in the Braintree_Transaction response object.

As such, you can generally rely on the status of submitted for settlement to reflect a valid, successful transaction.

We don't offer webhooks for transactions - instead, our API is designed to give instant feedback via the response object. Because of this, we only provide webhooks for asynchronous events that aren't triggered by an API call (such as billing a subscription or disbursing funds). We encourage our customers to avail of our API responses, in addition to our reporting system and comprehensive search call options, for any extra functionality they require.

If you wanted to pull updated statuses for transactions, such as to confirm a payment has settled, you could use the Transaction.find() API request, pass in the transaction ID and read in the status from the response object. This could easily be run as a script that iterates through the previous days transaction IDs and updates the status of each on a daily basis.

I hope this explains the transaction process with more clarity and offers you some options!

Kind regards,
Braintree

---

Just in case it helps!

Comment: so what about the case where I call `Transaction.Sale` and the internet connection times out or goes down - but the charge went through? I wouldn't have the ID to check for it! Which report could I use for this. I was hoping for a PayPal IPN style verification 'ping' and it's a shame it isn't available.

Answer (score 0):

I also asked kind of the same question to Braintree I got the same answer to check the transaction with Transaction::find() and then asked about the possibility of having a transaction not settled after having a SUBMITTED_FOR_SETTLEMENT status, here is the response, very clear and complete:

---

Hi Alban,

Thanks for reaching out with this question! Happy to help.

**Settlement Declined:**

In rare cases, a transaction that has been submitted for settlement will reach a status of settlement declined. For sales, this will only occur with a PayPal transaction. For refunds, this can occur with both PayPal and credit card transactions.

This occurs if the processor declined to settle the sale or refund request, and the result is unsuccessful. This can happen for a number of reasons, but the processor settlement response code may have more information about why the transaction was declined. Again, this status is rare, and only certain types of transactions can be affected.

- PayPal sale: We recommend checking the settlement status of all PayPal sale transactions before shipping goods or providing services to customers. To reduce these types of declines, submit your PayPal transactions for settlement either upon creation or within 3 days of creation.
- PayPal refund: We recommend contacting PayPal for details on refunds that are Settlement Declined.
- Credit card refund: Settlement declines can be hard or soft, just as with authorizations. In regions that support an immediate decline response for refunds, we will return Settlement Declined if the processor responds with a hard decline.

**Settlement Pending:**

This status indicates that the transaction has not yet fully settled. This status is rare, and it does not always indicate a problem with settlement. Only certain types of transactions can be affected.

--> PayPal sale:

- If using multiple partial settlements: Settlement Pending is a normal part of the transaction flow. The parent authorization will remain in this status until all child transactions are settled or the authorization expires. See the multiple partial settlement reference for more details.
- If not using multiple partial settlements: Almost all Settlement Pending PayPal transactions will settle without intervention, so we always return a successful result. In general, you can expect these to be updated to Settled within a few days as we confirm their status with PayPal. In the rare case we can't settle a Settlement Pendingtransaction, we'll contact you to resolve the issue.

--> Credit card, Android Pay, and Apple Pay sales: You will only see Settlement Pendingauthorizations if you have contacted us to enable a specific API feature that uses this status.

I hope that provides insight, Alban! Let us know if further questions arise.

Best,
xxxxx.
Braintree